# Method doesn't override method from its superclass

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am making a simple Android app to get the location of user using Google PlacePicker API and I'm getting this error:

> The @Override method gives error "Method doesn't override method from its superclass"

Below is my Code:

```
public class placepicker extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView locationtext;
    private final int REQUEST_CODE_PLACEPICKER = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_placepicker);

        locationtext = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.location);
    }

    public void getlocation(View v){

        startplacepickeractivity();
    }

    private void startplacepickeractivity(){

        PlacePicker.IntentBuilder intentbuilder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();

        try {
           Intent intent = intentbuilder.build(this);
            startActivityForResult(intent , REQUEST_CODE_PLACEPICKER);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override    << Error is here
    protected void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PLACEPICKER && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            displayplace(data);
        }
    }
}
```

I've searched for similar questions on Stack Overflow but none of these answers solved the problem. I can't figure out the issue with this. Can somebody help?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `o` is a lowercase `o`.

Comment: The annotation is doing its exact job. Note that you can usually let the IDE autocomplete these names, both saving time and avoiding this sort of error.

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks, It was just the Typo error here :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overriding wrong super class function. `onActivityResult`is the right function .use this

```
 @Override    
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PLACEPICKER && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

        displayplace(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) You have to explain what is the problem and how your code solves this. Don't just dump code and walk away;
2) There is an off-topic flag for typos.

Comment: Thanks it worked :) There was just typo error